# index list load faster in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a function that will display all the records from the database. Its fully working, but the problem's when the the records is more than 100 or up to 1000 and so on, it will takes a minimum of 7 to 10 seconds before it will display. How can can I make it faster. Here's my code using jquery.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.datainfo').show();
    $.getJSON('/dev/api/rrlist?cb=' + session_id, function(results){
        result(results);
        $('.datainfo').hide();
        var items = $("table.table tbody tr");
        var numItems = items.length;
        var perPage = 15;
        items.slice(perPage).hide();
        dothings(items, numItems, perPage);
    })
});

function result(results){
$.each(results, function(key, value){
$('table.table tbody').append('<tr> \
                <td><a href="/operations/purchase/'+value.id+'/showPurchaseReceiving">'+pad(value.id,8)+'</a></td> \
                <td>'+value.rr_date+'</td> \
                <td class="cuts">'+value.partner['name']+'</td> \
                <td class="cuts">'+(value.cb == 0 ? 'Head Office' : value.trans['name'])+'</td>\
                '+(! value.branch ? '<td></td>' : '<td class="cuts">'+value.branch['name']+'</td>')+' \
                <td style="text-align:right;">'+parseFloat(value.total_amt).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2,maximumFractionDigits: 2})+' '+value.deskpadcurrency['curr_code']+'</td> \
                <td style="text-align:center;">New</td> \
                </tr>');
})
}

function dothings(items, numItems, perPage){
    $(".pagination").pagination({
        items: numItems,
        itemsOnPage: perPage,
        cssStyle: "light-theme",
        hrefTextPrefix: '#',
        onPageClick: function(pageNumber){
            var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
            var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
            items.hide()
            .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you already given paging 15, so ideally logic is you must get only 15 records at a time to bind and while next / previous button the other 15 records take. this is faster too.

Answer (score 0):

This may be also a rendering performance problem. You can check your page performance with the built-in browser developer tool. Look for Layout, Recalculation Style or other counters.

You can speed up the table rendering by adding "table-layout: fixed" style, and setting explicit column widths.

Also worth a try to build the table content to a string html fragment, and append only once the full content.